# I need to increment variable in each line but also reset counter after line end

Tags: html, powershell, replace

I am a novice with Powershell so asking help here.

I need a PowerShell script which would read txt file and increment each x variable +1, but counter would reset after 1 line.

Sample(Original):

> Promotion begins at 12:00 am ET on May 8, 2017 **<x** id="8"
>   />and ends at 11:59 pm ET on June 9, 2017 (“**<x** id="9"
>   />Promotion Period **<x** id="10" />”)

Desired output:

> Promotion begins at 12:00 am ET on May 8, 2017 **<x1** id="8"
>   />and ends at 11:59 pm ET on June 9, 2017 (“**<x2** id="9"
>   />Promotion Period **<x3** id="10" />”)

This is one line so after it counter should be reseted to 1 again (1..n)

I found a script which gets all file contents and increments all values, which is not what I am after.

I am still researching so will update this later.

Update script so far:

```html
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("testfile")
#IF ([System.IO.File]::Exists($args[0])) { $contents = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($args[0]) } ELSE {  
   # ECHO "File does not exist!" }
try {
    for() {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
          
        $numbers =  
        [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($line, "&lt;x")

        for ($i = $numbers.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
{
    
    Write-Host ($numbers[$i].Index + $numbers[$i].Length)
    
    $line = $line.Substring(0, $numbers[$i].Index) +  
        ($i + 1).ToString() +  
        $line.Substring($numbers[$i].Index + $numbers[$i].Length)
}

        $line
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

It achieves the incrementation, but actual regex match dissapears
After code:

> Promotion begins at 12:00 am ET on May 8, 2017 **1** id="8" />and ends at >11:59 pm ET on June 9, 2017 (“**2** id="" />Promotion Period **3** id=
>   "10" />”).

It should be:

> Promotion begins at 12:00 am ET on May 8, 2017 **<x1** id="8" />and ends >at 11:59 pm ET on June 9, 2017 (“**<x2** id="" />Promotion Period >**<x3** id="10" />”).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Well said, you beat me to it.
Petras K - Please post an attempt so that we can help as the solution is not difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you posted is changing but missing the

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("testfile")
#IF ([System.IO.File]::Exists($args[0])) { $contents = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($args[0]) } ELSE {  
   # ECHO "File does not exist!" }
try {
    for() {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }

        $numbers =  [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($line, "\<x")

        for ($i = $numbers.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
        {

            Write-Host ($numbers[$i].Index + $numbers[$i].Length)
            $line = $line.Substring(0, $numbers[$i].Index) +  "<x" + ($i + 1).ToString() +  $line.Substring($numbers[$i].Index + $numbers[$i].Length)
        }

        $line
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

Comment: One last question as I understand I need to rewrite $reader part to get-content to actually save consoles output to file or is there a way to pipe  $reader to file?
Thanks again

Comment: You don't want to pipe reader there you want to write $line to a new file.   There are tons of resources for writing to files from PowerShell.  Give it a shot and if you need help post what you have with the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a script you tried so far, or do you expect the community to write it for you?

Either way, here's a start for the other members of the community to debug and perfect...

```
$content = 'Promotion begins at 12:00 am ET on May 8, 2017 <x3 id="8" />and ends at 11:59 pm ET on June 9, 2017 (“<x id="9" />Promotion Period <x id="10" />”)'
$test = ""

ForEach($line in $content){
$splitline = $line -match '\<x\d* id\='
switch ($Matches[0]){
     "<x id=" {$test = $line.replace($Matches[0],"<x1 id=") ; break}
     "<x1 id=" {$test = $line.replace($Matches[0],"<x2 id=") ; break}
     "<x2 id=" {$test = $line.replace($Matches[0],"<x3 id=") ; break}
     "<x3 id=" {$test = $line.replace($Matches[0],"<x4 id=") ; break}
     "<x4 id=" {$test = $line.replace($Matches[0],"<x5 id=") ; break}
     default {"Something else happened"; break}
     }
write-host $test
    }
```

I'm sorry, i'm not going to keep updating the snippet above as you make changes to the original post..